# Moving platform boosts player jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making game with unity where the player is cube and its jumping every time when it collides.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) // When collides with something
    {
        if(collision.contacts.Length > 0)
        {
            ContactPoint contact = collision.contacts[0];

            if(Vector3.Dot(contact.normal, Vector3.up) > 0.5) // If collision is from below
            {
                myRB.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpForce, 0)); // Auto jumping
            }
        }


    }
```

I made platform that moves up and down with animation but when my player jump on it the force gets boosted and it goes higher than it should. Is there any fix for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: higher than it should? how much is "should"

Comment: Try setting myRB's y velocity to zero before adding force. Also that's just how physics works

Comment: @LincolnC i want to jump the same as on not moving platform

Comment: @jkd Thanks but unfortunately this didn’t help

Comment: How big did you set the JumpForce? I'm surprised this works at all considering the ForceMode

Comment: what's your normal jump code? isit also just an `addForce`?

Comment: JumpForce is 350 and i managed to fix it half way by adding rigidbody to the platform but only work when the platform goes up

Comment: @IvailoHristov That's huge! try setting a much lower value and using [ForceMode.Impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html). While it may not directly fix your problem, it is better practice.

Comment: @LincolnC Yes its only addforce

Comment: @jkd Thanks but this didn’t worked. It does the same.

Comment: @jkd Sorry it seems that i didn’t test making the velocity 0 properly. It worked now. Thank you very much!